# Why does thermal energy supplied to a system decrease when there is an isothermal compression of an ideal gas?

Tags: thermodynamics

I am a HS student and am have gotten a question whose answer I do not understand.

Why does thermal energy supplied to a system, $Q$, decrease when there is an isothermal compression of an ideal gas?

Many thanks.

Comment: Are you familiar with (1) the ideal gas law, (2), the first law equation and (3) how the internal energy of an ideal gas depends on temperature.?

Comment: Yes. Sorry, had to edit the post...realised I wrote isobaric instead of isothermal

Comment: OK but still have you learned the three things I listed yet?

Comment: I have not understood your question. Can you please write what actually you are doing (I mean how you are compressing and when you are adding the heat)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\Delta Q = \Delta U + \Delta W$$

For an isothermal process $\Delta U = 0$ and work done $\Delta W = \int P dV$

As volume is decreasing, work done is negative and thus so is change in thermal energy.

Note that Q is the thermal energy of the system, whose absolute value we do not know, and $\Delta Q$ is the **change in thermal energy of a system** OR **heat supplied to the system** NOT the *change in thermal energy supplied to a system*.

In this case as $\Delta Q$ is negative it is actually the system that is supplying energy to the environment instead.